# How to get trading hours for shop

Tags: postgresql

I wish to get the trading hours for a shop.
My schema represents the opening time, and the duration which the shop is open, which is quite trivial.
An override table is provided to store dates which differ from the standard trading hours, or if the store is closed on a given day, or days. eg: Christmas day, or a weekend, etc.

How can I show the current week of days (Sunday to Saturday) with the relevant trading hours, and override hours for each respective day?

Schema and some SQL I have tried follows:

```
CREATE TABLE shop(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO shop(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Empire');
INSERT INTO shop(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Dodgey Joes');

CREATE TABLE trading_hours(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        time_open TIME NOT NULL,
        duration INTEGER NOT NULL, --In minutes
        day_of_week INTEGER NOT NULL,
        shop_id INTEGER REFERENCES shop(id)
);
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (1, '6:00', 720, 0, 1); -- sun 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (2, '6:10', 720, 1, 1); -- mon 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (3, '6:20', 720, 2, 1); -- tue 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (4, '6:30', 480, 3, 1); -- wed 8 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (5, '6:00', 720, 4, 1); -- thur 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (6, '6:00', 240, 5, 1); -- fri 4 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (7, '23:00', 240, 5, 1);-- fri 4 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (8, '6:00', 1200, 6, 1); -- sat 20 hours

INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (9, '7:00', 720, 0, 2); -- sun 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (10, '7:10', 720, 1, 2); -- mon 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (11, '7:20', 480, 2, 2); -- tue 8 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (12, '7:30', 510, 3, 2); -- wed 8.5 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (13, '7:00', 720, 4, 2); -- thur 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (14, '7:00', 240, 5, 2); -- fri 4 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (15, '12:00', 360, 5, 2);-- fri 6 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, shop_id) VALUES (16, '7:00', 1200, 6, 2); -- sat 20 hours
CREATE TABLE other_hours(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        time_open TIME NOT NULL,
        duration INTEGER NOT NULL, --In minutes
        day_of_week INTEGER NOT NULL,
        start_date DATE NOT NULL,
        end_date DATE NOT NULL,
        closed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        shop_id INTEGER REFERENCES shop(id)
);
-- shop 1 closed xmas day
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (1, '00:00', 0, 3, '2019-12-25', '2019-12-25', true, 1);
-- shop 1 closed every tuesday in January
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (2, '00:00', 0, 2, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-31', true, 1);

--shop 2 closed new years day
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (3, '00:00', 0, 3, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
--shop two closed Jan 10 to Feb 10
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (4, '00:00', 0, 0, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (5, '00:00', 0, 1, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (6, '00:00', 0, 2, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (7, '00:00', 0, 3, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (8, '00:00', 0, 4, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (9, '00:00', 0, 5, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (10, '00:00', 0, 6, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', true, 2);

-- shop 1 open 11:00am on Jan 2
INSERT INTO other_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week, start_date, end_date, closed, shop_id) VALUES (11, '11:00', 420, 4, '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', true, 1);
```

And some SQL:

```
elect th.day_of_week,
    case th.day_of_week
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Sun'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Mon'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Tue'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Wed'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Thu'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Fri'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Sat'
end AS day_name,
sh.name, th.time_open,
th.time_open +(th.duration::text||' minute')::INTERVAL AS time_close,
oh.time_open AS other_time_open,
oh.time_open +(oh.duration::text||' minute')::INTERVAL AS other_time_close,
case
  WHEN DATE(NOW()) >= oh.start_date AND DATE(NOW()) <= oh.end_date
        THEN oh.time_open
        ELSE th.time_open
  END AS kev_open_time
FROM trading_hours th
JOIN shop sh ON th.shop_id=sh.id
LEFT JOIN other_hours oh ON th.shop_id=oh.shop_id AND oh.day_of_week=th.day_of_week
ORDER BY sh.name, th.day_of_week, th.time_open
;
```

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` looks suspicious. It should be the date of the particular day of the week, shouldn't it? Or you assume that the `override table` contains always whole weeks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in a comment, `WHEN DATE(NOW()) >= oh.start_date AND DATE(NOW()) <= oh.end_date` seems wrong to me. `DATE(NOW())` should be rather the date of the particular day of the week.

I think I would start with generating dates for the days in the current week. Something like:

```
SELECT date, extract(dow from date) as day_of_week 
FROM (
  SELECT current_date + series AS date FROM generate_series(1,7) AS series
) AS "dates"
```

Or even better, aligning it with the week-days:

```
SELECT date, extract(dow from date) as day_of_week 
FROM (
   SELECT current_date - extract(dow from current_date)::Int + series AS date 
   FROM generate_series(0,6) AS series
) AS "dates"
```

which gives:

```
    date    | day_of_week 
------------+-------------
 2019-12-22 |           0
 2019-12-23 |           1
 2019-12-24 |           2
 2019-12-25 |           3
 2019-12-26 |           4
 2019-12-27 |           5
 2019-12-28 |           6
```

Now you can combine it with your query, using `dates.date` instead of `DATE(NOW())`:

```
SELECT 
  dates.date AS date,
  to_char(dates.date, 'day') AS day_of_week,
  sh.name, 
  COALESCE(oh.time_open, th.time_open) AS time_open,
  CASE
    WHEN oh.time_open IS NOT NULL
    THEN oh.time_open + (oh.duration::text||' minute')::INTERVAL
    ELSE th.time_open + (th.duration::text||' minute')::INTERVAL
  END AS time_close
FROM (
   SELECT current_date - extract(dow from current_date)::Int + series AS date 
   FROM generate_series(0,6) AS series
) AS dates
LEFT JOIN trading_hours th ON th.day_of_week = extract(dow from dates.date)
LEFT JOIN other_hours oh ON 
   th.shop_id=oh.shop_id AND 
   oh.day_of_week=th.day_of_week AND 
   dates.date >= oh.start_date AND 
   dates.date <= oh.end_date
JOIN shop sh ON th.shop_id=sh.id
ORDER BY sh.name, dates.date, time_open;
```